# How to show/hide grouped views in Android?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, visibility, android-view, show-hide

I want to create an activity such as mentioned in photo...
as soon as I press the maximize button I want it to become full screen for the activity and part 1 become minimize, and again when I press the restore button I want it to become in a first state: to be able to see part 1 and part 2 ...

I think if we put two layouts it is possible? Isn't it? Please refer me to a resource to help me about this, or show me the code to achieve a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Part one and two should be in their own layout. After, play with the `visilibity` property of each layout. Specifically to hide any view without it continues to occupy its space, use the value `gone` for the visibility property.

Ok, here I go. Below you have a complete example of how to hide/show grouped views.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextBox One" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="TextBox Two" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="TextBox Three" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Hide" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private boolean viewGroupIsVisible = true;  

    private View mViewGroup;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.viewsContainer);

        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {

    if (viewGroupIsVisible) {
        mViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mButton.setText("Show");
    } else {
        mViewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButton.setText("Hide");
    }

    viewGroupIsVisible = !viewGroupIsVisible;
}
```

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: how to put some widget into single group to give ability to hide all children widgets together?    for example: in vb.net we can put a panel or groupbox  as a container and we can invisible it and all items inside the panel or groupbox become invisible... i need something like this in android... thanks

Comment: I just edit my previous answer. Look at the example code that I have made.

Comment: please check this out      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886032/how-to-create-irregular-dialogbox-or-activity-in-android         thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit simplified solution, than Diego Palomar produced, without using additional variable. I'll take his code to show:

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 

    private View mViewGroup;
    private Button mButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mViewGroup = findViewById(R.id.viewsContainer);

        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View button) {

    if (mViewGroup.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mViewGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mButton.setText("Show");
    } else {
        mViewGroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButton.setText("Hide");
    }

}
```