# How to create a context menu on a ListView item in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, quickaction

As i mentioned in photo , i dont know what is this widget? 
and how to create it and use it in our project?

[image]

Comment: LinearLayout/RelativeLayout shown in a PopupWindow

Comment: @Atrix1987 would you please give me a simple code for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is called Quick Actions. I'm sure these projects will be helpful for you:

**[NewQuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D):** NewQuickAction3D is a small android library to create QuickAction dialog with Gallery3D app style.

**[NewQuickAction](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction)**: NewQuickAction is a small android library to create QuickAction dialog.

Comment: @diedo palomar  thanks again hero...   i ve another question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921786/how-to-creat-multiple-list-view-in-android