# how to create multiple list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview, header, scrollview

How can I create multiple list views within a single activity? Each `ListView` should have a separated header which allows expanding or collapsing its list, and scrolling on any `ListView` should scroll the entire activity (NOT one scroll for first `ListView` and another for second `ListView` ONLY one scroll for BOTH `ListView`...)

listviews dynamically fills...

Here's a screenshot of a similar view:

[image]

Comment: You can use Expandible ListView instead of Multiple ListView...

Comment: use exapnadable lsitview. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

The simplest way to create one is by changing your ListView in XML to `ExpandableListView` and use one of the implementations of [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) like `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` or `BaseExpandableListAdapter`, which work similarly to their non-expandable versions.

[Here's an example](http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html) from the Android samples API which you can download using SDK Manager.